# Cordova 5.4.1 Project same name while Import what should I do

Tags: java, android, node.js, eclipse, cordova

I am creating cordova project using update CLI with cordova version 5.4.1 using nodejs

followed the project creation procedure from

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html

if I am creating the project like

**C:\>cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld**

when ever I am importing the android project to my eclipse workspace it is giving my project name as "**MainActivity**"

[image: On Import of project in workspace..]

where as my expected name on import in workspace is "HelloWorld" project .

whenever I want to import a new project it will is giving me MainActivity already exist

It is not letting multiple project import in single workspace

suggest me with your valuable solutions what should I do...???????

Thanks in Advance

Yamini..

Answer (score 0):

try to check your previous projects and observe if there is no sort of matching or completely move your previous project to a new folder .